# Can I "jump around" in an XMLStreamWriter's output stream

Tags: stax

I just have this question around the Stax XMLStreamWriter. Best explained by example:

Say I need to produce a document somehow like this:

```
<buddies>
 <buddies name="tim"/>
 <buddies name="toady"/>
</buddies>
```

, where the tim and toady guys are created by some callback that receives the XMLStreamWriter as an argument.

```
writer.writeElement("buddies");
 callback1.writeBuddies(writer);
 callback2.writeBuddies(writer);
write.writeEndElement();
```

Now the thing is, the whole document must conform to a schema that states: If there's a `<buddies>` element, there must be at least one `<buddy>` inside, so if none of my callbacks write anything on the stream I'd have an empty  element which is invalid. Question is: Can I delay the `writeElement("buddies")` somehow like this:

```
// Pseudocode
Mark mark = writer.getPos()
boolean written = callback1.writeBuddies(writer)
written |= callback2.writeBuddies(writer)
if (written){
  writer.writeStartElement(mark, "buddies") // write at mark
  writer.writeStopElement() // write at the end of stream
}
```

Or am I completely off the track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StAX is a forward only streaming API. To achieve what you are asking is a potential requirement for DOM parser where you construct the node "buddies" separately and attach it to the main document if it is not empty.